# Можно ли полностью скопировать сервер

Tags: сервер, nginx, debian

Салют всем. У меня есть VPS на Debian 7. Там сайт на Django. Хочу с этим сайтом поработать(разобраться) на ноутбуке.
Установил на ноут Debian 7, pip, virtualenv...

Вопрос: Можно ли у себя на ноутбуке развернуть копию VPS со всеми nginx и тд? Чтобы функционировали локально на ноутбуке, все сайты с VPS

P.S.
Попытки перенести среду через pip freeze пока что не увенчались успехом (я так понимаю надо переносить среду определенную virtualenv, но как называется среда там на vps я не знаю). Потом возникают недопонимания на nginx...

Comment: а копирнуть файлы сайтов, и прописат хосты на ноутбуке, проблематично?

Comment: Нет, но не совсем понимаю как.

Comment: ну файлики можно копирнуть по ssh через [scp](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php), или же через ftp используя какой-то клиент (например [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/))

Comment: Файлы сайтов только? Или всего сервера целиком от root'a? Просто с php сайтами у меня проблем в принципе нет, а вот с python впервые столкнулся ступор какой-то.

Comment: сайтов, зачем вам прям все, я не думаю, что вы не сможете установить на ноутбуке программы/либы которые вам нужны

Comment: если же вы использовали git-репозитории, по типу github или gitlab, то тогда проблем с переносом вообще не должно быть

Comment: Установить в принципе не сложно, а вот понять, что мне нужно установить - сложнее) Да использовали BitBuсket (это же вроде аналог?). Ладно, благодарю, буду по этому пути идти

Comment: Просто хотелось, пару волшебных заклинаний и получить копию VPS на ноуте, чтоб не думать что надо установить))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто - как два байта переслать. С помощью stage4, например: http://gentoo-wiki.gentoo.ru/wiki/Stage4

Comment: да, благодарю, похоже на то, что надо. А можно ещё один глупый вопрос: Там написано надо установить Gentoo. Я почитал что Gentoo -  это дистрибутив GNU/Linux из которого можно слепить почти что угодно. Т.е. мне надо на ноут поставить вместо Debian - Gentoo, потом по указанным командам выполнить операции? При этом с VPS никаких изменений не произойдет?

Comment: @МихаилСоснин Вам не нужна Gentoo, там просто на примере Gentoo показано как делать stage4. Его можно сделать из любого linux дистрибутива. Но если Вы этого никогда не делали, то будет сложновато первый раз :(

Comment: Теперь гораздо яснее, буду разбираться, благодарю.